# jQuery Toggle and hide or show hide is there a better method than this (jsfiddle included)

Tags: jquery

In an app i'm working on it uses jQuery toggle mostly to open and close divs. I know the same effect can be done using show and hide. I have an example in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peter/Srun8/). Is either method better than the other? Or is there another method more efficient and compliant to open and close divs only allowing one to be open at a time? Thanks

Also i'm moving my app over to use Twitter Bootstrap if it matters

```
<div id="wrapper"> Toggle Method
<div id="action-buttons">
    <a class="button" onclick="$('#boxone').toggle();$('#boxtwo').hide();return false;"><span>One</span></a>
    <a class="button" onclick="$('#boxtwo').toggle();$('#boxone').hide();return false;"><span>Two</span></a>
</div>
<div id="boxone" style="display:none;">Box One</div>
<div id="boxtwo" style="display:none;">Box Two</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper"> Show Hide Method
<div id="action-buttons">
    <a class="button" onclick="$('#showboxone').show();$('#showboxtwo').hide();return false;"><span>One</span></a>
    <a class="button" onclick="$('#showboxtwo').show();$('#showboxone').hide();return false;"><span>Two</span></a>
</div>
<div id="showboxone" style="display:none;">Box One</div>
<div id="showboxtwo" style="display:none;">Box Two</div>
</div>
```

​

Comment: Notice how the answers below leverage the power of jQuery to get rid of your inline JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest removing the style and actions from the HTML part.

And don't try to optimize it : there is no performance problems on such basic jQuery actions and the only thing that matter is the readability of the code : be sure your HTML, CSS and Javascript are obvious. Don't try to make too smart javascript : if you can't instantly see what it does, there are risks of maintainability problems. And rely on id, classes and specific attributes instead of order properties that won't keep up when you change your page.

Here's how I changed your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PRVm8/

HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper"> Toggle Method
<div id="action-buttons">
    <span class="button1"  target=boxone>One</span>
    <span class="button1"  target=boxtwo>Two</span>
</div>
<div id="boxone" class=box1>Box One</div>
<div id="boxtwo" class=box1>Box Two</div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper"> Show Hide Method
<div id="action-buttons">
    <a class="button2"  target=boxone><span>One</span></a>
    <a class="button2" target=boxtwo><span>Two</span></a>
</div>
<div id="showboxone" class=box2>Box One</div>
<div id="showboxtwo" class=box2>Box Two</div>
</div>
​
```

Javascript :

```
$('.button1[target="boxone"]').click(function(){
    $('#boxtwo').hide();
    $('#boxone').toggle();
});
$('.button1[target="boxtwo"]').click(function(){
    $('#boxone').hide();
    $('#boxtwo').toggle();
});
$('.button2').click(function(){
    $('.box2').hide();
    $('#show'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

​

Comment: Thanks since i'm moving to bootstrap, do you see any problems using their Dropdown method? It has the CSS/jQuery and HTML separated and is what i'll be installing http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know this plugin enough to issue a recommendation. It seems fine but generally I try to avoid UI plugins as I find preferable to write myself 5 or 10 lines of javascript/jquery and be sure to be able to change it when my needs change. Each time I tried a plugin I had to finally drop it.

Comment: It's more a framework not a plugin cross browser compliant etc.

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Srun8/2/)*

*"...allowing one to be opened at a time"*

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper"> Super method
    <div class="action-buttons">
        <a href="#"><span>One</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span>Two</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">Box One</div>
    <div class="box">Box Two</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper"> Super method
    <div class="action-buttons">
        <a href="#"><span>One</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span>Two</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">Box One</div>
    <div class="box">Box Two</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    display:none;
}
```

jQUery:

```
$('.action-buttons').on('click','a',function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    var $allbox = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.box'),
        $box = $allbox.eq( $(this).index() ),        
        doIt= ($box.is(':visible')) ? $box.slideUp() : ($allbox.slideUp()) ($box.slideDown());   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a better method in jQuery, but another way to go is to use either:

- [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)
  or
- [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).