# jquery error undefined function

Tags: jquery

I created this fiddle from code found on Stack, but it is firing an error. Can you help please.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/422steve/DVNGc/

Original anser : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000179/501173

Error I am getting is: TypeError: $allExtended.slideUp() is not a function

js:

```
$('.holder').on('click','a',function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    var $allExtended = $(this).closest('.wrapperdoo').find('.extended'),
        $extended = $allExtended.eq( $(this).index() ),        
        doIt= ($extended.is(':visible')) ? $extended.slideUp() : ($allExtended.slideUp()) ($extended.slideDown());   
});
```

Comment: It does not even has a correct syntax. `($allExtended.slideUp()) ($extended.slideDown())` What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is going on - in your ternary operation, on the last line, you are trying to call two functions. That is not possible. You need to use an `if` block. Here is how I rewrote it. I don't know if you are using the `doIt` variable for any purpose, but you will want to check for `undefined`:

```
$('.holder').on('click','a',function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    var $allextended = $(this).closest('.wrapperdoo').find('.extended'),
        $extended = $allextended.eq( $(this).index() ),
        doIt = undefined;

    if ($extended.is(":visible")) {
        doIt = $extended.slideUp();            
    } else {
        $allextended.slideUp();
        doIt = $extended.slideDown();
    }  
});​
```

**--- EDIT ---**

To add the class to the href that is being clicked, just do it like this, in the function:

```
$(this).addClass('class');
```

If you want to remove the class when you are done, do it like this. First, assign the this variable as a global variable (so the `this` variables don't get mixed up), like so:

```
var sender = $(this);
```

Then, in your `slideUp()` or `slideDown()` functions, the second parameter is a callback for when it is completed:

```
$allextended.slideUp(500, function() { sender.removeClass('class'); });
```

Comment: one slight issue. I need to append a class to the a href that triggers the slide down, as within the container div there are other a href links. Is there a fix for this that you can think of, lets say the a href class was .placed

Answer (score 1):

`($allextended.slideUp()) ($extended.slideDown())` is very wrong.
The code you wrote calls `slideUp()`, then calls the return value of `slideUp` as a function, passing `slideDown()`.

It looks like you're trying to run two statements; to do that, you need an `if` block.